# Characters after / are treated as comment in HTTP Header Manager in JMeter 5.1.1

Tags: jmeter, http-headers

I upgraded my Jmeter from 3.2 to 5.1.1 but now having problems running my script as HTTP Header Manager treated all characters after / as comment

[HTTP Header Manager Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq1N3.png)

[/ treated as comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJePV.png)

How can i fix this one?

Comment: It's not a functional issue, only display issue

Comment: Hello @user7294900, right now I run the same scripts both in JMeter 3.2 and 5.1.1 and it is working on 3.2. but getting <Msg>Your session is not valid.</Msg> issue on 5.1.1. What might cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It’s just displayed this way. There is nothing to fix here.

The header is really sent as defined